# Changing order of display fields in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, code-behind

I've searched this and the answer doesn't seem to work.  I've got the following function in C# code-behind:

```
public void Show_Data2(string LPI_ID)
{
    OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();
    try
    {
        {
            //conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCST"].ToString();

            OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd3.CommandText = "SP_LPI_REGISTER_CLAIM_DETAILS";
            cmd3.Connection = conn;

            cmd3.Parameters.Add("vLPI_ID", OracleType.VarChar, 20).Value = LPI_ID;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("vClaimDetails", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            //connection2.Open();

            var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);

            DataGrid_ClaimDetail.DataSource = ds;
            DataGrid_ClaimDetail.DataBind();

            // The problem happens here:
            DataGrid_ClaimDetail.Columns["Item"].DisplayIndex = 0;
            DataGrid_ClaimDetail.Columns["dt"].DisplayIndex = 1;
            DataGrid_ClaimDetail.Columns["UserName"].DisplayIndex = 2;

            if (DataGrid_ClaimDetail.Items.Count < 1)
            {
                lblEmpty2.Visible = true;
                lblEmpty2.Text = "There is no data to display";
            }
            else
            {
                lblEmpty2.Visible = false;
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I've got the following DataGrid in asp.net:

```
<div id="divGrid2" style='width:920px; height:230px; overflow:auto;'>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid_ClaimDetail" runat="server" Visible="true"
AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
OnCancelCommand="DataGrid_ClaimDetail_CancelCommand" 
OnUpdateCommand="DataGrid_ClaimDetail_UpdateCommand" 
OnEditCommand="DataGrid_ClaimDetail_EditCommand">
                <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
                Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <Columns>
                <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CancelText="Cancel" 
                        EditText="Select" UpdateText="Update"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>

        </asp:DataGrid>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty2" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

If I take out the 3 DisplayIndex lines in the C# code, it works fine, but my fields aren't in the order I'd like.

If I put those lines back in, I get an error on each line of code:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

and each of the field names is underlined.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong, or tell me how I'd be able to re-order the fields in the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

`DataGrid.Columns` [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumncollection(v=vs.110).aspx) has only [`this[Int32]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumncollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx) indexer, so you can't access its items by their names (`cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'`). To use it you have to know the required index:

```
DataGrid_ClaimDetail.Columns[3].DisplayIndex = 0;
```

So how would you get columns by their names?

There seems to be no `Name` property on the [`DataGridColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx), but you can try to use the [`HeaderText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.headertext(v=vs.110).aspx) property of each column, that in standard databinding scenario should be equal to the original DB column name:

```
var columns = DataGrid_ClaimDetail
    .Columns
    .Cast<DataGridColumn>()
    .Where(col => // Not sure but some button columns may be headerless
        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(col.HeaderText))
    .ToDictionary(
        keySelector: col => col.HeaderText,
        comparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

columns["Item"].DisplayIndex = 0;
```

Or you can try the same with [`BoundColumn.DataField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.datafield(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var columns = DataGrid_ClaimDetail
    .Columns
    .OfType<BoundColumn>()
    .ToDictionary((
        keySelector: col => col.DataField,
        comparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: With respect to the first part; **'DataGridColumn' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayIndex' and no extension method 'DisplayIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @JohnyBones Hmm, I didn't actually check the code assuming that such property exists. In such a case you would probably have to manually reorder the columns by removing/adding them from the `Columns` collection. And I will try to get a working prototype when I have a time, probably tomorrow.

Comment: After a bit of googling, it seems like maybe this only works in Windows.Forms, whereas I'm using this on an Intranet website?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I came to a solution.

The first thing I did was change from a DataSet to a DataTable.  This allowed me to use the SetOrdinal property.  It also allowed me to use the Visible property in the code-behind.

```
var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
var ds = new DataTable();
SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);

ds.Columns[0].SetOrdinal(1);
ds.Columns[1].SetOrdinal(2);
ds.Columns[2].SetOrdinal(3);

DataGrid_ClaimDetail.DataSource = ds;
DataGrid_ClaimDetail.DataBind();

DataGrid_ClaimDetail.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

In order to do this, I had to change the AutoGenerateColumns on the ASP side to "false".  I then hard-coded the column names in the `<Columns>` tag:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CancelText="Cancel" 
         EditText="Select" UpdateText="Update"></asp:EditCommandColumn>

    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Status" DataField="Item" />
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Date" DataField="dt" />
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Who" DataField="UserName" />
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="UserID" DataField="UserID" ItemStyle-Width="0px" />

</Columns>
```

By changing the column's Visible property, it still allowed me to access the value I store in the UserID field (which gets used in the OnClick event of the button created in EditCommandColumn).

Not *quite* as neat as I hoped for, but it got the job done.